# Django model attribute to refer to arbitrary model instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, generic-relations

I'm working on a logging app in Django to record when models in other apps are created, changed, or deleted. All I really need to record is the user who did it, a timestamp, a type of action, and the item that was changed. The user, timestamp, and action type are all easy, but I'm not sure what a good way to store the affected item is beyond storing an id value and a class name so the item can be retrieved later. I imagine that storing the class name will result in a bit of a hacky solution in order to find the actual class, so I'm wondering if there's a better way. Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [generic relations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) which do just that (use instance id and model class) but are integrated in Django and you also get a shortcut attribute that returns related instance so you don't have to query it yourself. [Example usage](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/generic_relations/).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [generic relations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).